# Using node.js and the discord.js library to message users when I run a command, but it only starts to work after the targeted user runs the command

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

Like I said in the title, I'm trying to create a Discord bot that messages a user upon me running a command. It only works, however, after the targeted user runs the command themselves. After they run the command. I can run it and it messages them. If I restart the bot, the targeted user needs to run the command for it to work again. Why is this happening? I assume its possible to make it so they don't need to run the command first.

The code I am using is this:

```
if (cmd === "cmd1"){
  bot.users.get("<user1ID>").send("Message");     
}

if (cmd === "cmd2"){
  bot.users.get("<user2ID").send("<Message>");
}
```

If I try to run, say cmd1, before user1 runs cmd1, it will throw an error in the console saying "TypeError: Cannot read property 'send' of undefined." The bot and users are in a mutual server. It seems to me like the issue is that the users are not being cached until the user themselves runs the command. I would like it to be so I can run the command to message people without them having to do so first. The purpose is to notify a few people of a pre configured message.

Comment: With .cache, it shows the error cannot read property 'get' of undefined and without .cache, it says cannot read property 'send' of undefined.

Answer (score 0):

Because of Discord.js V12, you need to add a `cache` when fetching members by ids

```
bot.users.cache.get("<user1ID>").send("Message");
```

Comment: Now its saying `TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined`. Do I need to initialize a cache or something?